# How to make ToString() method for a list of customs struct

Tags: c#

I have the following struct:

```
struct entry
{
    public string msg;
    public UInt32 ts;
    public bool newLines;

    public entry(string message, UInt32 timestamp, bool lines = false)
    {
        msg = message;
        ts = timestamp;
        newLines = false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return msg + (newLines ? "\n" : "");
    }
};
```

I am using a List of these structs in my program, in some parts of the program I need to take the list of these entry's, and combine them back into a long string separated by newlines.  My question is is my ToString() method going to work with a `List<entry>`?  Or do I need to override another function?

Thanks

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  If you are going to provide a `override` method for `ToString()` you can make it function anyway you want.  So as to your ultimate question **My question is is my ToString() method going to work with a List<entry>?** of course it will you can make it work ANYWAY you want.

Comment: If your list of entries is going to be long, then you should probably provide a new method that converts a list of entries to the desired string.  If you create a ToString overload, it might be called in some cases when you don't want a very long string (for example, in the debugger).  This would also save you from having to create a new type just for the purpose of overriding ToString.  If you're new to the language, and have time to play around, then I'd recommend experimenting with both approaches so you can learn what works best for you, and why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to make a custom class that inherits List like this:

```
public class EntryList : List<entry>
{
   public override string ToString()
   {
      //return what you want
      //EDIT:  accessing items
      foreach (entry e in this)
         //...
   }
}
```

Comment: One could also just create a new function instead.  All you need is a reference to the `List<T>` which isn't a problem in this case.

Comment: I'm still new to C#, I think the `EntryList : List<entry>` is extending on the class of List<entry> right?  How would I access the data of the List<entry>? Do I need to declare some variables and a constructor?

Comment: @MasterGberry you would use the EntryList just as you use a `List<entry>` (thanks to the Liskov substitution principle).  For example: `List<entry> theList = new EntryList();`

Comment: @MasterGberry, see my edit for how to access the items in the list.

Comment: Thanks :)  Was super helpful, unfortunately the extra foreach is slowing down my program a lot xD gotta try to get clever with a solution

Answer (score 3):

It is not going to work for `List<entry>` because you are overriding `ToString` of entry struct. You can simply use `string.Join`:

```
var fullString = string.Join(",", entries);
```

You can also create new type which would inherit form `List<entry>` in which you can override `ToString`.

Answer (score 2):

Build your own 'EntryList' that derives from List < entry > and override ToString().

Another tip - use a StringBuilder in your ToString implementation to more efficiently build your uber-string.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a whole new subclass, you could use an extension method that has that method. However, as others have mentioned, hydrating a long list as a string is probably not the right thing, and will have odd effects (especially in the debugger).

regardless of implementation :

Its probably more correct to have the list tostring reflect some state of 
the list (total number of items, sum of values, etc) rather than dumping the details of every item.